# PyHook: return keydown fires twice

Tags: python, winapi

In the following code, when I hit return, on_key_down gets called twice.  It only gets called once for any other key.  Any idea what's going on here?

```
import pyHook, pythoncom, win32api

def on_key_down(e):
  if e.MessageName == 'key down':
    print 'e.Key: ', e.Key
    print 'e.Ascii: ', e.Ascii
  return True
hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = on_key_down
hm.HookKeyboard()    
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Window's New Line is a '\r\n' you are probably getting both of those characters when you hit return.

Comment: No, I don't think that's it.  I edited my code to print the ascii value, and it's 13 both times, which is the code for \r.

Comment: Interesting.  Have you considered writing C and interfacing directly with the winapi to see how it behaves?

Comment: Eh...  it's been a few years since I wrote any C.  It'd be a pita to get setup.  I think I'll just work around the issue for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, try using KeyUp instead of KeyDown. I only get one event with KeyUp.